# SQL Server - Passing a common parameter to all the stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In my project we want to introduce a change where we want to stop using `SYSTEM_USER` in all the stored procedures and want to pass the current user personal number so that procedure won't decide the user's personal number, but we will pass it to the procedure.

The obvious way is to pass the current user personal number as a parameter in all the stored procedures, but it is cumbersome.

Is there any way to pass this parameter in some other way, maybe by setting a global variable before calling the procedure and accessing it inside it, or maybe by passing something in connection to the string.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Session Context Information](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252(v=sql.105).aspx):

> Session context information differs from Transact-SQL variables, whose scope is limited to the current Transact-SQL batch, stored procedure, trigger, or user-defined function. Session context information can be used to store information specific to each user or the current state of the application. This can then be used to control the logic in Transact-SQL statements.

However, a limitation here is that this context has to be (re-)established each time that a connection to the database is opened. If you're following modern norms of application development, in which connections aren't kept open for long periods of time but are only opened close to the point of use and closed immediately afterwards, then this introduces some small amount of additional complexity because you need to ensure that the session context is re-established each time.

I'm not aware of any way to "preset" this context information from the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the connectionstring for that.

In the connectionstring you can put an extra option `Application Name=yourusernumber;`

and in the stored procedure you can read this like this :

```
 declare @AppName varchar(20)
 select @AppName = APP_NAME()
```

A connection string could look like this

```
Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=MY_DB;Data Source=SQLSERVER\XXX_192;User ID=sa;Password=XXX;Application Name=123456;
```

where 123456 is the userID.

What I do is in my client I add this to the connectionstring like this :

```
string locWinUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
_connectionString = File.ReadAllText(appUDLFile) + ";User ID=sa;Password=XXX;Application Name=" + locWinUser + ";";
```

that way the APP_NAME() in my triggers and stored procedures is always filled with the network user name that was used to login.
But this is my way of logging, you can adapt this to your needs of course.

Answer (score 0):

I like the connection string idea but if not, you could make a function to get the UserID and then call the function in your stored procedures when you need to retrieve it.

Comment: and  where does this function would retrieve the userid from ?

Comment: depends, I have no idea what your system is.  Where would the userID come from? Or how can you get the userID?  This is only really if you can't use the connection string method which seems the most intuitive in my opinion but again, decides on what your actual system is.

Comment: I dont know, ask the OP. But if you have no idea where to get the userid then what use is your answer ?

Comment: You seem to mis understand the question, the OP wants to pass a userid to the database that he can use in stored procedure and  he askes how he can do that. Your answer does not helps with his question

Comment: Oh, I assumed you were the OP.  Well I dont have rep to leave a comment so best I can do is take a shot at an answer.  And he never said to the database, he said to the stored procedure but didn't want a parameter for the userID.  If he can't use the connection string method, then another way is to make a function that retrieves the ID and then call that.  He wouldn't need a parameter for each stored proc and he could change his `SYSTEM_USER` to his new function.  I like to think you're not actually asking me how to get his userID when no one on this thread knows where it comes from :/

Comment: no you misunderstood. He has no means of getting a userid so he wants his client connection to fill up something in the database that he can use in stored procedures. So a function wont help at all because he still needs a way to push the userid somehow with his connection

Comment: and yes the question is 'how can i get the userid'. That is exactly his question. He wants to know how he can pass the 'userid' with his connection and store it somewhere so he can use it in his stored procedures. Using a function to retrieve it is not his problem, where to retrieve it from, that is exact his question

Comment: But, according to OP, a global variable set before the stored procedure is executed would fulfill the requirements.  That does not mean that he is trying to pass it with his connection.  He just wants a straightforward, less cumbersome way of passing a UserID that comes from somewhere.  A function, if not connection string, can perform this, depending on where his userID comes from.  He was using SYSTEM_USER before, so don't see why he couldn't place the logic of that in a function and effectively create a GetUserID().  Then he can call that and if the logic every changes, change the function.

Comment: No that is not what he is asking. He wants to know how he can set a global variable, or how he can pass something from the connectionstring.

Comment: SYSTEM_USER always returns the same, 'sa' for example. He wants an unique user id instead. But sql server has no such info, only what comes from the connection string and from the session. So he has 2 options. 1. pass the userid in every call to a stored procedure from his client. 2. pass the userid from his client just once to the client's connection or session, and use that. His question is how he can do the second option

Comment: Once he has achieved the second option ,than he can use a function to retrieve it. But first he has to know how to achieve the second option